# How to Match only url from a tag node js

Tags: regex, node.js, url, xregexp

I have a tag `<a href="#caveat1"><span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);">[1]</span></a>`

I am using this regex `<a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>` But its not parsing the url only. Its also parsing `<span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);">[1]</span>`

How can i get only the url from a tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily! Capture everything that is between `href`, that is a key word, and `<`.

```
href=(.*?)>
```

If you don't want to capture `""`, try this one:

```
href="(.*?)">
```

Although I am not much experienced with node.js, I think this one may work, but it won't be hard for you if you know the Regex.

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/href="(.*?)">/);
```

Here is [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sO5iQ7/1%C2%A8).

Comment: Sorry, But it seems its not working when the url has something like this `<a href="https://www.hivehome.com/" title="Hive Active Heating">asdfasdf</a>` Its capturing `https://www.hivehome.com/" title="Hive Active Heating`

Comment: Oh Ok. I'll use `<a href="(.*?)" (.*?)>(.*)<\/a>`

Comment: Use `href="(.*?)"[ |>]` to capture your link. In every case after link there is a white space or the tag ending character`>`.